# specific redux reducer situation with react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, state

I have

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BuilderState } from "store";
import { connect } from "store/helpers";

export interface JobBuilderOptimiseProps {
    pageState: BuilderState;
}

interface JobBuilderOptimiseDispatch {
    getPreview: () => void;
}

import "./JobBuilderOptimise-styles.scss";
import { Row, Col, Button, Panel } from "react-bootstrap";
import { ProjectName } from "../controls";
import { JobPostingControl } from "components";

@connect<JobBuilderOptimiseProps, JobBuilderOptimiseDispatch>(
    state => ({ pageState: state.pages.builder })
)
export class JobBuilderOptimise extends React.Component<JobBuilderOptimiseProps & JobBuilderOptimiseDispatch> {
    render() {
        const {
            jobPosting,
            search,
            previewByTemplate,
            getFrequentlyBuiltJobsState
        } = this.props.pageState;

        return (

            <div className="optimise-page">
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={7} >
                        <div className="optimise-panel">
                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>
                    </Col>

                    <Col sm={5}>
                        <div className="preview-panel">
                            <JobPostingControl jobDescription={jobPosting.data} isLoading={search.previewRequestState.isBusy || previewByTemplate.isBusy} leftSide={this.props.children}/>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

{this.props.children} should load one of two pages. Based on which page is loaded, I have to pass in a prop to JobPostingControl (which I can add) called emptyText which is of type string. So two different strings based on which page gets loaded. I want to use state so that when either the search page or model page (the two pages) is loaded I can dispatch an event stating that the empty text should be "...". I believe i need a seperate reducer. Please help

Comment: It seems like typescript to me which I'm not familiar with, you should add another tag for typescript so someone good at it could help.

Comment: Added, even if you don't know typescript, can you offer any help?

Comment: Looks like what you need is to dispatch another action that updates the empty text inside `JobPostingControl`. If you want the action to be dispatched after the `JobPostingControl` is loaded, then you just need to dispatch an action that updates the empty text, inside the `componentDidMount()` in `JobPostingControl`.

Comment: How would this dispatch look like? can you provide some code even in javascript

Comment: You could refer to one of my sample project [here](https://github.com/choo737/Hout). But it is in javascript.

Comment: what portion am I supposed to be looking at?

Comment: here is the path that you should look at => Hout/src/components/eventlist.jsx, I think I also found quite a good [example](http://www.mattgreer.org/articles/typescript-react-and-redux/) for you.

Comment: `mapStateToProps(state)` is taking the state from Store.getState() and `mapDispatchToProps(state)` is taking the dispatch from Store.Dispatch([actionObject]). The connect function at line 35 connect the state and the dispatch to the container class (in my case it is eventList).

Comment: does the sample and the link helps?